# Pivoting a table in Blazor

Tags: c#, sql-server, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a SQL Server table which looks like this:

```
Month | Percentage
1         5
2         6
3         8
4         10
```

I would like to show this table in a Blazor view but pivoted such that it looks like :

```
Month      1  2  3  4
Percentage 5  6  8  10
```

I wanted to know if something like this is possible as I have never worked with pivots in c# before

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: @HenkHolterman How would that work though?

Comment: I have never seen a table go horizontal in HTML, as dumb as the sounds :( im used to making a foreach that stores vertical...

Answer (score 2):

Like Henk said in the comments, you can use 2 foreach loops

```
<table class="table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Month
        </td>
        @foreach (var val in YourSqlTableModelList)
        {
            <td>@val.Month</td>
        }
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Percentage
        </td>
        @foreach (var val in YourSqlTableModelList)
        {
            <td>@val.Percentage</td>
        }
    </tr>
</table>

@code{
        protected List<YourSqlTableModel> YourSqlTableModelList { get; set;}

        public class YourSqlTableModel
        {
            public string Month { get; set;}
            public string Percentage { get; set;}
        }
        
        //call the method to get the values from the sql server table
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a website that shows how to pivot a table, if that is what you need :)
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22008/C-Pivot-Table